# Getting piece of string in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to get some of string with jQuery.
Ex:

```
<div class="example">
My sentence: xxxxxx
</div>
```

EDIT :"xxxxxx" is a variable.
I want to get a piece after "my sentence:". How can I do it?

Comment: For this question to be properly satisfied, we need to know more about the token `My sentence:`. Will it contain different text? Will it always be trailed by a `:`? Are you really just looking for the string of text following the first instance of a `:`?

Comment: We also need to know more about the actual sentence, represented above by `xxxxxx`. Can you guarantee that it will never contain `:` or `My sentence:`? If you can guarantee these two exceptions, then one of the variations below using `split` can be used. Otherwise, you will need to use a combination of `indexOf` and `substring` methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this -

```
var text = $('.example').text().split(':')[1];
```

Demo `----->` http://jsfiddle.net/czW9x/

Comment: See my comments about Adil's code below. You'd have to split on `My sentence:` rather than just `:`.

Comment: ^And that's assuming that `My sentence:` cannot appear in the `sentence` section of the text.

Answer (score 0):

What is the selection based on? You can't just type something and say I want to select this specific text. 
Multiple ways to achieve what you need, read the following and use what suits your requirement:

http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2012/06/jquery-string-functions.html

Comment: thanks for your source, I added this to my bookmarks.

Answer (score 0):

You actually want to find the first index of `:` and then get the substring following that.

```
var text = $('.example').text();
var sentence = text.substring(text.indexOf(':') + 1);

alert(sentence);
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ENSnN/6/)